# Azure SQL Server table taking unreasonable space

Tags: azure-sql-database

I got a table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[INIT_AccessControl](
    [timestamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DatabaseConnection] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Creation DateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [User Security ID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Role ID] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Company Name] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [Scope] [int] NULL,
    [App ID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [User Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Role Name] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [App Name] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_INIT_AccessControl] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

That, in our test environment, is taking this much space with these very few records:

```
TableName                Rows        Reserved_KB    Data_KB      Index_Size_KB   Unused_KB    Data_MB       Data_GB
------------------------ ----------- -------------- ------------ --------------- ------------ ------------- ---------------
INIT_AccessControl       5773        4412960        2153808      2249848         9304         2103.328125   2.054031372070
```

While in our production database, with more than three times the same amount of records:

```
TableName                Rows        Reserved_KB    Data_KB      Index_Size_KB   Unused_KB    Data_MB       Data_GB
------------------------ ----------- -------------- ------------ --------------- ------------ ------------- ---------------
INIT_AccessControl       19922       17552          6952         7264            3336         6.789062      0.006629943359
```

I'm currently out of my depth, I can see that the test version has many more pages than the prod version, but I can't see how to reclaim that space of if it's even open to be reclaimed.

Pages taken in test:

```
TableName             RowCounts   TotalPages   UsedPages   UnusedPages
--------------------- ----------- ------------ ----------- -------------
INIT_AccessControl    4166        551564       550310      1254
```

And in production:

```
TableName             RowCounts   TotalPages   UsedPages   UnusedPages
--------------------- ----------- ------------ ----------- -------------
INIT_AccessControl    19922       2226         1806        420
```

Some records were deleted between the two queries, pardon the discrepancy.

Comment: What is your [Fill Factor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/specify-fill-factor-for-an-index?view=sql-server-ver15) for your Indexes on the Table?...and for that matter, what Indexes do you have defined?

Comment: Have you defragmented the indexes in your test/dev environment?  Do you have compression turned on in production (I don't think it shows up by default with the script object command)

Comment: @J.D. There's an index for customer ID and the PK, both with fill factors of 0 in both environments.

Comment: @JonathanFite an ex-colleague suggested rebuildind the indexes and that did the trick. I'm still interested about why this happened, so I'm going to investigate the compression bit.

Comment: The empty space inside a page won’t be reclaimed until it’s defragmented.